# Regex to remove span having id without data

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-group

I have this string. I want to remove span having id without removing the data.

**Input:**
var testString = `"<span class="test01">Electrical drafting Scheduling tools <span id="spcc15in0os0">draftin</span><span> </span> Scheduling tools Mechanical</span>"`

**Expected Output:**

```
"<span class="test01">Electrical drafting Scheduling tools draftin<span> </span> Scheduling tools Mechanical</span>"
```

I am new to regex. Tried few things.

Try1: `testString.replace(/<\/?span\sid=[^>]*>/g, "")`
Result: But it is not removing the closing Tag of span

Try2: `testString.replace(/(<span id=".*"(?: \w+="[^"]+")*>([^<]*)<\/span>)/gi, "")`
Result: it is removing span having id with data.

Comment: don't use regex to parse html content

Comment: As @ArunPJohny has said, [**don't use regex to parse html**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) you can, however, use jQuery, just put you html string in `$(myStringHere)`

Comment: In which environment you want to parse this string? Server/Client-side? If you have javascript available you can do it much simpler just using [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse HTML via regex, if you don't have to. You tagged your post with `jquery`, so this could work out for you:

```js
var testString = "<span class='test01'>Electrical drafting Scheduling tools <span id='spcc15in0os0'>draftin</span><span> </span> Scheduling tools Mechanical</span>";

var $element = $(testString);
$element.find("span").each(function(index) {
    var innerText= $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith(innerText);
});

var newString = $element.html();

console.log(newString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```